# WebExtensions Native messaging shuts down targeted application too quickly

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

In a background.js file I use the following to start a program on my computer:

var sending = browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage("program",json_obj);

It shuts down the program only after a few seconds even though the program needs to run for a little longer. On other computers that I have tested, the program runs fast enough to complete execution.

The documentation says:

> A new instance of the application is launched for call to runtime.sendNativeMessage(). The browser will terminate the native application after getting a reply. To terminate a native application, the browser will close the pipe, give the process a few seconds to exit gracefully, and then kill it if it has not exited.

So it seems like a reply message from the program is leading to the shutdown.

I am using an example similar to the one shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

Except that I am running a jar file instead of a python one. I have not put `@echo off` in the batch file because then the Java program does not start at all. I need to delay the reply from the native application so that the Java program can finish executing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `connectNative()` instead of `sendNativeMessage()`, the native application will be kept alive as long as the created Port is alive in the browser (ie until you explicitly close it or the page from which it was created is unloaded)